# How to create absolute links in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm using Node.js with Express, Connect, and Jade. I want to provide an absolute link to a route in my application, but I can't find how to do this. I must be missing something, because this seems like a simple task.

I can do this: /myroute

But what I want is this: http://localhost:3000/myroute

There must be a helper somewhere that does this, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created my own helper for this, which doesn't feel like the greatest solution.

```
Helpers = {
    toAbsolute: ( url, req ) ->
        'http://' + req.headers.host + url
}

DynamicHelpers = {
    req: ( req, res ) ->
        req
}

exports.Helpers = Helpers
exports.DynamicHelpers = DynamicHelpers
```

I add the helpers in my app.coffee file:

```
helpers = require './helpers.js'

# Helpers
app.helpers helpers.Helpers
app.dynamicHelpers helpers.DynamicHelpers
```

In my [jade] view, this is what I do to get an absolute URL from a relative URL:

```
| <a href="#{ toAbsolute( '/relativeUrl', req ) }">link text</a>
```

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer for now, due to lack of response, and this is the best thing I could manage to put together. I think it will help people. As soon as I find a better solution, I'll update the question/answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'helper', but you could write your own by injecting req.query variables into the jade local variables for the route.

Personally, I'd do it client-side using window.location.origin.

Answer (score 0):

**update**: actually, this only seems to work if req is from a POST, not a GET. :(

**update 2**: ugh, it's not even consistent across browsers. and neither is tim's. To find the solution I ended up using, google "window.location.origin considered harmful".

---

req.headers.origin appears to return something like 'http://example.com:1234' when the browser hits 'http://example.com:1234/something'.

this seems to be the express equivalent to @timoxley's client-side solution. :)

It's only a little bit simpler than yours, but it removes the need for a literal 'http' (or https).